# How can I create Android Intent with Action on Google(android assistant)?

Tags: android, android-intent, actions-on-google

I want to create Android Intent with Google Assistant.
I'll ask "Ok Google, show me some specific information from my app" and google assistant should open my app via Android intent.
Anyone faced with this issue?

Comment: FWIW: I have an Action wherein I display a Basic Card with a button that is associated with an endpoint on my website. The identity that I use to publish my Android app is associated with my website. My Android app has an intent filter that maps URIs on my website to an Android activity. When someone taps the link on the card if my app is not installed on his phone then he sees a page that offers to download it. If the app is installed, an activity runs and parses the URI to to decide what to do next. It is a tad more clunky than deep linking which is _still_ in preview but it works.

Answer (score 2):

[App Actions](https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/) were announced at Google I/O in 2018, but are not yet publicly available.

Similarly, [Deep Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#android_link) to an Android Intent have been available in developer preview.